# Where should I plugin the Authorization in Asp.net WebAPI?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, authorization

As I see I have 3 possible places to plug my stuff in the pipeline

```
1)     AuthorizationFilters

2)     Action Filters

3)     DelegatingHandler
```

The most obvious one is AuthorizationFilters , where I can decorate my actions/ controllers with my custom authorization attribute . say .. `MyCustomAuthorizationAttribute` .

Since HTTP message handlers are in the first stage in the processing pipeline. Does it make any sense to put it in there ?

Authorization for me right now simply means checking a token in the header which is given to the client after authentication.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update July 2014**

My original answer covered WebApi 1. with WebApi 2 there were some changes i.e. there is now an `IAuthenticationFilter` meaning you can move authentication logic out of the `DelegatingHandler` which is a little more elegant.

There is a Nuget project [here](https://github.com/mbenford/WebApi-AuthenticationFilter) that offers an implementation of IAuthenticationFilter and also explains some background to its introduction.

OWIN middleware is now perhaps the best place to implement your authentication logic - there is an example of Certificate Authentication [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana/) and Basic Authentication OWIN Middleware here in [this blog post](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-using-owin-middleware/) the former example is the preferred one as it demonstrates the use of the base `AuthenticationHandler` class.

The advice on `AuthorizationFilters` remains largely unchanged.

**End Update**

Typically...

Use `DelegatingHandler` to carry out Authentication... i.e. who someone is. Use this to set the Principle of the Thread and User context, add claims etc. You can place authorisation logic here too but on a fairly global scale. I would personally always use AuthorizationFilters for authorisation.

Use `AuthorizationFilters` to restrict controllers and actions to specific people. These are used when you can extrapolate their permission with the information in claims, principal, url or the http request parameters. The default authorisation filter can be used to restrict access to anonymous users or by roles (if set in something like a delegating handler) - obviously you can implement your own AuthorizationFilters too if you need it.

Occasionally use `ActionFilters` when you need to make the decision over authorisation using the message content e.g. you need access to a property on the entity to decide whether they have access (obviously be careful with this(!)).

Note:

The `AuthorizationFilters` are called before the content of the body is read therefore they do not have access to the message body to make authorization decisions this is why the `ActionFilters` specifically the `OnActionExecuting` is used to occasional raise authentication errors.

**So**

In your scenario I would put a simple `DelegatingHandler` to take your header and set the principal.

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{


    public CustomAuthenticationMessageHandler ()
    {

    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                                                           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Authenticate(request);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected virtual void Authenticate(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {

        var authorisationHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (authorisationHeader == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Ensure you are happy with the header contents then

        {
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(//new Identity , //Roles);
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }

    }
}
```

Then use `AuthorizationFilters` to restrict access:

```cs
    [Authorize]
    public string Get()
    {

    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public string GetAdminOnly()
    {

    }
```

**To register the global Authentication**

```cs
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomAuthenticationMessageHandler());
```

This will mean that in every request the principal will be set to either null or a valid identity. It won't handle authorisation i.e. wont deny access to any controllers or actions.

**To start protecting resources**

Either target protected controllers and actions with the standard or custom [Authorize] attributes. Or register globally:

```cs
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

And only white list the controllers and actions you want unsecured using the  `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute.

**If you only want authentication on some routes**

Then you can modify your `DelegatingHandler` a little to set the `InnerHandler` to route to the correct controller e.g.

```cs
public CustomAuthenticationMessageHandler(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
       InnerHandler = new HttpRoutingDispatcher(configuration);
}
```

And then you can specify this handler on your routes like so:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "myurl",
            defaults: new {},
            constraints: new {},
            handler: new CustomAuthenticationHandler(config)
            );
```

Comment: Does that mean I will checking the authorisation per request in the request pipeline..upside being I can eject from the pipeline sooner if the authorisation is not there..should this be configured per route basis assuming I could have some routes which do not require any authorisation/authentication..

Comment: I would add the authentication to every route by registering the message handler config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomAuthenticationMessageHandler());

The Authorisation is easy implement in a variety of ways. One approach if most of your site is secure is to register the Authorize filter globally config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute()); and then just pepper the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the controllers or action you want left unsecured.

Comment: How would you get this to work with Self hosting WebApi?

Comment: There is the new `IAuthenticationFilter` which gives you another option ;-)

Comment: @Kugel thanks for the comment - I have tried to add some advice for WebApi 2 users.