# Claims Auth with OWIN Self Hosted WebApi

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, claims-based-identity

I am self hosting WebApi with the following configuration:

Visual Studio 2012 / .NET 4.0

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // authentication
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new Shield.PresharedKeyAuthorizer());

    // routing
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

I have a simple test setup with the following `DelegatingHandler` to create a claim and attach it to the current thread.

```
public class PresharedKeyAuthorizer : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "superstar"));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "PresharedKey");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

However, when I hit the `ApiController` that is marked with the `Authorize` attribute, it doesn't recognize the authentication.

```
[Authorize]
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Secure File A", "Secure File B" };
    }
}
```

Removing the `Authorize` attribute and setting a breakpoint, I can see that RequestContext.Principal property is indeed null. The request works fin without the `Authorize` attribute, so I know the setup of the self hosting is correct, but I must be missing something in the authentication pipeline.

What am I missing to allow that claim to work against the `Authorize` attribute?

This related answer with the same approach appears to work when hosted by IIS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872968/118224

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the message handler, set the principal like this.

```
request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;
```

Do not use

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

**UPDATE**

It has been a while since I worked on .NET 4.0/2012/Web API <2. So, I cannot answer for sure. But with OWIN hosting, principal must be set in the OWIN context. `OwinHttpRequestContext` sets both `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and the principal in OWIN context. By using `request.GetRequestContext().Principal`, these details are hidden from you. To make long story short, I **believe** if you some how set the principal in OWIN context, this will work. Not sure how you can do that from web API message handler. You can do that from OWIN middleware.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id}");

    //config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PresharedKeyAuthorizer());

    app.Use((IOwinContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "superstar"));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "PresharedKey");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        context.Request.User = principal;
        return next.Invoke();
    });

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: Is this only available in WebApi 2.0? I am running .Net4.0/VS2012, which I will add to my answer.

Comment: Yes, but aren't you already using web API 2? I thought you are checking `Principal` on `HttpRequestContext`.

Comment: Your correct, I am using webapi2. I'm actually using the AuthorizeAttribute on the Controller, which should be checking the Current thread principal I believe.

Comment: `[Authorize]` gets principal like this - `IPrincipal user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;`.

Comment: Thanks your first answer is correctly working now. It took me some time realize the `[Authorize]` attribute coming from WebApi has a different implementation than `[Authorize]` coming from System.Web. I just needed to reference the correct one. For portability, I am going to set all three values so it works regardless of where it gets hosted.

Comment: Gald it works. You don't need to set it to accommodate all types of hosting. `request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;` already does that for you.

Comment: Thanks! Allowed me to avoid making a custom authorize attribute.

Comment: @Badri In newer versions it uses `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as `actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext` is no longer available in later versions of WebApi.

Comment: Thanks!
the code that you provide in "UPDATE" works for me.
With this I was able to configure self-host webapi for development purpose with some always logged in used for testing purposes